# Subset netCDF in python based on another variable

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a netCDF file where I want to replace some data based on another variable in the netCDF file. The file is available here: https://umd.box.com/s/lrb12vl7bxbqpv2lt0c27t8m0ps0nm0e 
and has the following structure:

```
  dimensions:
    lat = 720;
    time = 3;
    lon = 1440;
  variables:
    float cntry_codes(lat=720, lon=1440);
      :_FillValue = 0.0f; // float

float data(time=3, lat=720, lon=1440);
  :_FillValue = NaNf; // float
  :units = "%";

int time(time=3);

float longitude(lon=1440);

float latitude(lat=720);
```

I want to replace the 'data' values in the grid cells (where the cntry_codes value is 840) to a new value of 0.8. I am trying to subset like this:

```
import netCDF4
lat_inds = numpy.where(cntry_codes = 840.0)
lon_inds = numpy.where(cntry_codes = 840.0)
```

However, this just does not work. Any better solution?

Comment: The code you provide doesn't work. First you should read your data using `data = netCDF4.Dataset(...)`, then access the variables you need, `cntry_codes = data.variables['cntry_codes'][:]`, then play with them, `mask = cntry_codes[cntry_codes = 840.0]` and, finally, modify the data you want for the `data` var in the nc file.

Comment: thanks @kikocorreoso, It is the final step which is confusing me. I.e. how do I modify the data var based on the masked array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import netCDF4 as nc

dataset = nc.Dataset('/path/to/data.nc', 'r+')

cntry = dataset.variables['cntry_codes'][:]
shape = dataset.variables['data'].shape

for i in range(shape[0]):
    data_i = dataset.variables['data'][i]
    data_i[cntry == 840.0] = 0.8
    dataset.variables['data'][i] = data_i

dataset.close()
```

Now, your data.nc file should be updated with the new info. Tell me if it helps.

The docs for the netCDF4-python library are [here](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/).